# How to make a custom class iterable in Pug?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pug

So, I have this custom paginator class, and in it I have implemented the methods [Symbol.iterator] and forEach:

```js
class MyPaginator<T>{

  items: T[]

  //...

  [Symbol.iterator](){
    return this.items[Symbol.iterator]();
  };

  forEach(callback: (item: T, index: number) => void): void {
    return this.items.forEach(callback);
  }

  //...
}
```

With this, I can iterate through it in "normal" code with

```js
for(let element of paginator) {}
// or
paginator.forEach(elements => {})
```

But apparently pug does not use any of those for it's `each` iterator, because this does not work:

```
ul
  each element in paginator
    li
      // something
```

Although this works:

```
ul
  each element in paginator.items
    li
      // something
```

Is there anything I can implement in my class so that I'm able to iterate through it in Pug without needing the `.items`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each-of` with `Symbol.iterator` if you are using `pug >= 3`.

```
ul
  each item of paginator
    li= item
```